# Injecting @Service bean into non spring class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a websocket-config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new MessageHandler(), "/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionIdHandshakeInterceptor());;
    }
}
```

And i am facing structure crysis. As you can see, **MessageHandler** class is not @Service class. However the class itself needs reference to @Service classes. I provide the refference for **MessageHandler** from application context using:

```
ApplicationContext context = WebSocketService.getAppContext();
WebSocketService webSocketService= (WebSocketService) context.getBean("webSocketService");
```

However, the class needs more than 1 refference. I could just stack code above for all dependencies, or i could make **MessageHandler** @Service class, and autowire all dependencies.

Maing **MessageHandler** @Service class i will be unable to pass it as argument into **addHandler()** method. However i could do:

```
public MessageHandler getHandler(){
    ApplicationContext context = WebSocketService.getAppContext();
    return (MessageHandler) context.getBean("messageHandler");
}

public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(getHandler(), "/websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionIdHandshakeInterceptor());;
}
```

Which could save my from redundancy of code. However i feel unsure, whetever its good practice.

Is there any other way how to do this or am i stuck with this?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Why are you unable to pass it as argument to addHandler, if it's a Spring bean? Just let it inject in your WebSocketConfig class and pass that object then to the method call.

Comment: Doesn’t matter if it is annotated or not. As long as it is a bean it is enough to use for DI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to create a non-spring-managed bean:

```
public CreateOrderCommand createOrderCommand(Integer userId, Integer productId, Integer count) {
    CreateOrderCommand command = new CreateOrderCommand();
    command.setProductId(productId);
    command.setUserId(userId);
    command.setBuyCount(count);
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(command);
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(command, command.getClass().getName());
    return command;
}
```

This is inspired by how spring to autowire a test class.